# How can i create a custom renderer for a DatePicker (rounded corners, background color,etc)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

So i first had an awesome solution for an Entry and i was able to easily customize the properties in the xaml. But now i would like to have a solution for a DatePicker, i've tried to do it the same way but i was unable to get it working.

I mainly want to be able to change the background color, border, rounded border and add some padding. But with the solution i tried i was only able to change the colors when you pick a date..

Would be awesome if someone could help with that and possibly explain how to do it on IOS also.
Thanks a lot.

[image]

But what i really want is the DatePicker to look like the green Entry

[image]

**HERE'S WHAT I DID FOR THE ENTRY :**

TextEntry.cs :

```
public class TextEntry : Entry
    {
        public static BindableProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CornerRadius), typeof(int), typeof(TextEntry), 0);

        public static BindableProperty BorderThicknessProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderThickness), typeof(int), typeof(TextEntry), 0);

        public static BindableProperty PaddingProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Padding), typeof(Thickness), typeof(TextEntry), new Thickness(5));

        public static BindableProperty BorderColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderColor), typeof(Color), typeof(TextEntry), Color.Transparent);



        public int CornerRadius
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);
            set => SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value);
        }

        public int BorderThickness
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(BorderThicknessProperty);
            set => SetValue(BorderThicknessProperty, value);
        }
        public Color BorderColor
        {
            get => (Color)GetValue(BorderColorProperty);
            set => SetValue(BorderColorProperty, value);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// This property cannot be changed at runtime in iOS.
        /// </summary>
        public Thickness Padding
        {
            get => (Thickness)GetValue(PaddingProperty);
            set => SetValue(PaddingProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

**TextEntryRendererAndroid.cs**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TextEntry), typeof(TextEntryRendererAndroid))]
namespace maPaye.Droid
{
    public class TextEntryRendererAndroid : EntryRenderer
    {
        public TextEntryRendererAndroid(Context context): base(context)
        {

        }

        public TextEntry ElementV2 => Element as TextEntry;
        protected override FormsEditText CreateNativeControl()
        {
            var control = base.CreateNativeControl();
            UpdateBackground(control);
            return control;
        }
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == TextEntry.CornerRadiusProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                UpdateBackground();
            }
            else if (e.PropertyName == TextEntry.BorderThicknessProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                UpdateBackground();
            }
            else if (e.PropertyName == TextEntry.BorderColorProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                UpdateBackground();
            }

            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        }

        protected override void UpdateBackgroundColor()
        {
            UpdateBackground();
        }
        protected void UpdateBackground(FormsEditText control)
        {
            if (control == null) return;

            var gd = new GradientDrawable();
            gd.SetColor(Element.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
            gd.SetCornerRadius(Context.ToPixels(ElementV2.CornerRadius));
            gd.SetStroke((int)Context.ToPixels(ElementV2.BorderThickness), ElementV2.BorderColor.ToAndroid());
            control.SetBackground(gd);

            var padTop = (int)Context.ToPixels(ElementV2.Padding.Top);
            var padBottom = (int)Context.ToPixels(ElementV2.Padding.Bottom);
            var padLeft = (int)Context.ToPixels(ElementV2.Padding.Left);
            var padRight = (int)Context.ToPixels(ElementV2.Padding.Right);

            control.SetPadding(padLeft, padTop, padRight, padBottom);
        }
        protected void UpdateBackground()
        {
            UpdateBackground(Control);
        }
}
}
```

**Now i tried to reproduce that for the DatePicker but wasn't able to add border/corner radius/back ground color to the entry box where you choose the date**

**DatePickerEntry.cs**

```
   public class DatePickerEntry : DatePicker
    {
        public static BindableProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CornerRadius), typeof(int), typeof(DatePicker), 0);

        public static BindableProperty BorderThicknessProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderThickness), typeof(int), typeof(DatePicker), 0);

        public static BindableProperty PaddingProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Padding), typeof(Thickness), typeof(DatePicker), new Thickness(5));

        public static BindableProperty BorderColorProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderColor), typeof(Color), typeof(DatePicker), Color.Transparent);



        public int CornerRadius
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);
            set => SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value);
        }

        public int BorderThickness
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(BorderThicknessProperty);
            set => SetValue(BorderThicknessProperty, value);
        }
        public Color BorderColor
        {
            get => (Color)GetValue(BorderColorProperty);
            set => SetValue(BorderColorProperty, value);
        }

        public Thickness Padding
        {
            get => (Thickness)GetValue(PaddingProperty);
            set => SetValue(PaddingProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

**DatePickerRendererAndroid.cs**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(DatePickerEntry), typeof(DatePickerRendererAndroid))]
namespace maPaye.Droid
{
    public class DatePickerRendererAndroid : DatePickerRenderer
    {

        public DatePickerRendererAndroid(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }
        public DatePickerEntry ElementV2 => Element as DatePickerEntry;
        protected override EditText CreateNativeControl()
        {
            var control = base.CreateNativeControl();
            UpdateBackground(control);
            return control;
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == DatePickerEntry.CornerRadiusProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                UpdateBackground();
            }
            else if (e.PropertyName == DatePickerEntry.BorderThicknessProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                UpdateBackground();
            }
            else if (e.PropertyName == DatePickerEntry.BorderColorProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                UpdateBackground();
            }

            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        }

        protected void UpdateBackground(EditText control)
        {
            if (control == null) return;

            var gd = new GradientDrawable();
            gd.SetColor(Element.BackgroundColor.ToAndroid());
            gd.SetCornerRadius(Context.ToPixels(ElementV2.CornerRadius));
            gd.SetStroke((int)Context.ToPixels(ElementV2.BorderThickness), ElementV2.BorderColor.ToAndroid());
            control.SetBackground(gd);

            var padTop = (int)Context.ToPixels(ElementV2.Padding.Top);
            var padBottom = (int)Context.ToPixels(ElementV2.Padding.Bottom);
            var padLeft = (int)Context.ToPixels(ElementV2.Padding.Left);
            var padRight = (int)Context.ToPixels(ElementV2.Padding.Right);

            control.SetPadding(padLeft, padTop, padRight, padBottom);
        }
        protected void UpdateBackground()
        {
            UpdateBackground(Control);
        }
}
```

Comment: don't know which step you have done now, you want to create custom DatePicker like the first picture you provided?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Yea it wasn't really clear sorry, but i want the entry of the DatePicker to look like the text entry we see on the picture  ( With rounded border like on android, with a background color). On android you only have a line for the DatePicker entry, but i want it to be like the text entry on the screenshot. But what i've done only changed the look of the date picker when you open it but that's not what i wanted to do haha. Thanks :) ( I want it to look like the entry where u see Commentaire in the place holder)

Comment: you can change `this.Control.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.#533f95);  
this.Control.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);  
this.Control.SetPadding(20,0,0,0);  
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();  
SetCornerRadius(25); //increase or decrease to changes the corner look  
SetColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);  
SetStroke(3, Android.Graphics.Color.#533f95);  
this.Control.SetBackgroundDrawable(gd); ` in DatePickerRenderer